# Kendo Grid, how to change value on model but keeps it in cell?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using autocomplete method for cell edit in Kendo Grid.

If I selected some value from autocomplete I'm able to set selected ID (not text value) into model using following code:

```
 change  : function (e) {
                 options.model.set("parentProject", "123");
             },
```

But problem is that this code sets also visible text in the cell.

Is possible to set text of the Selected value into cell but set ID to the model without need to create hidden model fields ?

Many Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yea, I've done this with a dropdownlist. You need to set the `ClientTemplate`to be the textual representation of the widget. Could you show some more code from your grid?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work.

```
columns.Bound(e => e.SportId).Title("Fav Sport").ClientTemplate("#=SportName#")
                                                .EditorTemplateName("SportsList");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may assign the item value at the datasource.

```
$("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data()[yourRow].parentProject = "123";
```

If you call set() on an item it will update the ui (if the item is editable).

Comment: Hello, could you tell me please, how did You Get yourRow values?